# How can i add up unused disk to existing partition folder

Tags: filesystems, storage

[image: system storage]

I have an unused 1TB HDD and I need to add it to my main storage /dev/sda3, how can I do this without modifying the files on that partition?

Comment: You can't really unless /dev/sda3 was an LVM volume. You can mount your new volume to a location within /, but you can't create a disk span with partitions already in use without LVM or other storage pooling system like zfs.

Comment: Aw, ok. Can i do this if i reinstall the OS? Or can't be done period?
I guess i need RAID0? (i have multiple backups of this data)

Comment: LVM is probably more convenient to manage this. Many distributions offer installation options with LVM.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it. Can i do it with LVM without losing the data? if so could you post that as a solution?

Comment: @MichaelRogers I did pretty much just write that answer. Though I've got to say, if you have a backup of your data, reinstallation might very plainly be orders of magnitudes easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all. sda3 is simply a partition on sda, and not on sdb. You can't change that.

What you can do is have a multi-disk volume that spans multiple disks, but first only includes sdb. you copy your 513 GB data from sda3 to that volume, then you erase sda3, and add it as second storage backend to that volume.

Three choices, basically:

1. ZFS volume
2. BTRFS volume
3. LVM + filesystem of your choice

I'll go with option 3, as it might be the most well-trodden path under linux.

The thing about LVM is that you can, at any point, add (and remove, given enough remaining space) physical volumes to and from volume groups, create and delete logical volumes (which behave like partitions, but aren't "bound" to the single physical medium) on that group.

### In-system method (no reinstallation)

1. you need to make sdb an LVM physical volume: `sudo pvcreate /dev/sdb`
2. create a volume group (which will later span two physical volumes) on that: `sudo vgcreate michaelsgroup /dev/sdb`
3. create a volume on the volume group; we'll grow it later. `sudo lvcreate --name michaelsvolume --size 800 G michaelsgroup`
4. make a file system on it (you can pick any file system, but I choose XFS, which can be resized online): `sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/mapper/michaelsgroup-michaelsvolume`
5. mount that (I picked `/mnt` as mountpoint, but pick whatever emtpy directory you like!): `sudo mount /dev/mapper/michaelsgroup-michaelsvolume /mnt`
6. copy over the data, but only that from the same filesystem: `sudo cp -ar --one-file-system / /mnt`
7. Adjust your `/mnt/etc/fstab` and your `/etc/fstab` accordingly
8. Update your bootloader configuration, so that it knows the root partition is now an LVM volume. This will require your boot system to be LVM-aware! that's usually not a problem, but it can be on some linux distros.
9. Reboot; if anything went wrong, you can always boot from usb, change the /etc/fstab and bootloader config on /dev/sda3 back to its prior state
10. if it worked, then /dev/sda3 is not mounted anymore, and can be converted to a physical volume using `sudo pvcreate -f /dev/sda3` (this is the point where you lose all data on /dev/sda3), and then be added to the volume group: `sudo vgextend michaelsgroup /dev/sda3`
11. finally, we make the volume with the file system on it span both disks: `sudo lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/michaelsgroup-michaelsvolume`

### Reinstallation Method (probably easiest)

You With modern Linux distros, the installer will allow you to select LVM as "partitioning scheme". If you [choose "manual partitioning" and then "LVM" instead of what is selected by default](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/latest/install-guide/install/Installing_Using_Anaconda/#sect-installation-gui-manual-partitioning), you get the LVM setup on sda, and then can add sdb as physical volume already during installation, or later.

Comment: 4th choice is madm raid0

Comment: not a proper use case for that, imho. Why would you want to use an md raid0 without LVM? That seems strange.

Comment: I wasn't recommending it, but it does solve the goal.

Comment: It honestly doesn't, unless you can teach the initrd to set that up. That's pretty much where LVM came from.